# Autosized table of 100% width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I'm building some sort of reporting-functionality where the user can select a number of elements to be part of the report.
The number of possible elements can vary depending on the users needs.
Also the content for each element can vary as of this is user-content.

The report(s) can be printed via browser, exported as pdf or just previewed in browser. It's also possible to set landscape/portrait mode to get what fits the needs best.

Question: Is there any way to make the table always 100% width (e.g. DIN A4 size for printing) and have the column-widths matching there content overflowing at some given point?

If I set the table-style to

```
.reportTable{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;    
}
```

and the style for `th` to

```
.reportTable th{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

the rendered table has the correct size and all columns the same size with it's content hidden in case it is too long.

And here is the problem. If one column only shows a number it takes the same space as the column showing the name of an user. For printing (where space is not infinite) this is lost space which can be used for other things which may get cut off.

Changeing it to

```
.reportTable{
    width: auto;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;    
}
```

will size the columns depending on the content. But, if the content is too long, the table will be bigger than 100% (some kind of out of bounds).

Is there any way doing this with pure `css` or do I need `javascript`/`jQuery` (which for sure is an option)?
No plugins or something external.

Answer (score 0):

You may keep table width at 100%. whatever screen size be there it will set as per resolution. for th table header define width in "%" so that it can take width of column in that proportion. If numbers are in td set respective th at lower width %.

Comment: But if I don't know the exact number of elements (table-columns) this could lead to invalid markup, no? Worst case (not a real use-case): 101 elements -> each 1% width would lead to 101% overall-width.